# OBI Analytics server fails to start

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, weblogic11g, obiee

I installed OBI server and the em and console are working but the analytics server fails to start and reports a 500 error with the following message in the console. I do have the weblogic server running at 7001 port. I am not sure if there is a web service I need to enable to expose the credentials for alias ADF and bi-default.

I currently have the following two providers of Authentication in myrealm: 
 1. DefaultAuthenticator - WebLogic Authentication Provider and
 2. DefaultIdentityAsserter - WebLogic Identity Assertion provider

Can someone advise me what I am missing here?

```
 127.0.0.1:7001 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect].>
<Jan 23, 2014 8:09:20 PM PST> <Error> <oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ConnectionsHelper> <BEA-000000> <Failed to get credentials for alias ADF and
connection name bi-default
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: oracle.security.jps.service.idstore.IdentityStoreException: JPS-01520: Cannot ini
tialize identity store, cause: oracle.security.idm.ConfigurationException: javax.naming.CommunicationException: 127.0.0.1:7001 [Root exception is java
.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect].
        at oracle.adf.share.security.providers.jps.JpsUtil.getDefaultIdentityStore(JpsUtil.java:386)
        at oracle.adf.share.security.providers.jps.JpsUtil.getDefaultIdentityStore(JpsUtil.java:363)
```

Comment: Have you configured your servers `listen-address` to be something other than blank (e.g. use the actual ip).

Comment: Yes, I did. How to I know from where Oracle picks the address to connect and how I can bind to that address?